# Tcolorbox with boxed title

Tags: tcolorbox

[image: Tcolorbox with boxed title]

How do I make this in `LaTeX`? Sorry, I'm just a beginner and I can't find a specific video on youtube on how to make these, and those on the internenet are too complex and advancec.

Comment: So what have you got so far? What's the issue? I'd suggest to start with an example, and take it from there. Check out https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/master/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-example.tex e.g.

Comment: This exact layout is directly given in the Tcolorbox manual, p178.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE, hope the below code meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow,colframe=red,fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=red,enhanced,attach
boxed title to top center={yshift=-10pt},title={\color{white}My title}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`tcolorbox` having beautiful documentation and so many styles of boxes are defined in document itself, please refer it.